# How do I change my gmail password from Lollipop?

Tags: google-account

I am running Lollipop and want to change my gmail password. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page in your webbrowser: https://myaccount.google.com/security/signinoptions/password

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your @EMAIL for Android (not the one for Gmail and not in your account settings).
2. Select the email account then hit your menu tab. Go to -> **More** -> **Account settings** -> **Incoming** -> change your new password here.

If this doesn't work, change your password in outcoming too.